# Allow powershell console to show in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, powershell, spawn

I've got a NodeJS (Electron) client which is running the following code:

```
child = spawn("powershell.exe",['-ExecutionPolicy', 'ByPass', '-File', require("path").resolve(__dirname, '../../../../updater.ps1')]);
child.on("exit",function(){
    require('electron').remote.getCurrentWindow().close();
});
```

The file that this opens is a powershell file which downloads and unpacks an update. If I run this file manually, I get the powershell console which shows me a progress bar for the download and the unpacking. However, running it from code like above does not show the console.

How can I make my code show the powershell console during it's runtime? I'm having a hard time formulating search terms to find an answer to this.

Things I've tried:

- Adding `'-NoExit'` to my 2nd parameter array
- Adding `{ windowsHide: false }` parameter
- Adding `'-WindowStyle', 'Maximized'` to 2nd parameter array

I've also tried switching to `exec`.

```
exec('powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ' + updater_path, function callback(error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log(error);
});
```

Which runs the file but still doesn't show the console.

An answer will preferably allow me to run powershell files un-attached to the NodeJS client, and will also show the powershell console while running.

Here is my current code:

```
updater = spawn("powershell.exe",['-ExecutionPolicy', 'ByPass', '-File', remote.app.getAppPath() + '\\app\\files\\scripts\\' + data.type + '_updater.ps1'], { detached: true, stdio: 'ignore' });
updater.unref();
```

Which actually does nothing, it doesn't even seem like it runs the script at all.

I've tried the same thing using a batch file, it's never opened.

```
updater = spawn("cmd",[remote.app.getAppPath() + '\\app\\files\\scripts\\launch_updater.bat'], { detached: true, stdio: ['ignore', 'ignore', 'ignore'] });
updater.unref();
```

Comment: Add `'-NoExit'` inside of your array?

Comment: @AdminOfThings That did not work, it doesn't even pop up for a second. It runs, just no console

Comment: Is it possible the windowsHide option is behaving like it is set to true? I believe the default is false `{ windowsHide: false}`.

Comment: @AdminOfThings I added `, { windowsHide: false }` after my array, and it doesn't seem to have done anything

Comment: About the only thing left I can think of is if the window is hidden....`'-WindowStyle', 'Maximized'`

Comment: @AdminOfThings No change still unfortunately

Comment: Found this possibly related github issue https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/8795

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually worked around this by using `exec` to call a batch file, and this batch file runs the powershell file.

```
//call buffer .bat file, close main window after 3 seconds to make sure it runs before closing.
exec('start ' +  remote.app.getAppPath() + '\\app\\files\\scripts\\launch_updater.bat ' + data.type);
setTimeout(function() {
    require('electron').remote.getCurrentWindow().close();
}, 3000);
```

launch_updater.bat:

```
@ECHO OFF
set arg1=%~1
start powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -File "%~dp0/%arg1%_updater.ps1"
for /f "skip=3 tokens=2 delims= " %%a in ('tasklist /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe"') do (
    if "%%a" neq "%current_pid%" (
        TASKKILL /PID %%a /f >nul 2>nul
    )
)
exit /b
```

The loop in the batch file is essentially just so it will close itself without leaving a command window open. I pass an argument based on what kind of update it is.

Answer (score 4):

The `shell:true` and `detached:true` where enough to open PowerShell.

I've made this simple **demo** for a detached **PowerShell** window:

- root:

  - index.js ( aka your main js file )
  - powerShell.js ( the detached powershell window)
  - showTime.ps1 ( aka your file )

In `powerShell.js` will find that i separated the arguments that keep the PS Window open under the `defaultPowerShellArguments` variable.

> **Advice**: I see alot of `powershell` at the `spawn` command parameter, i cannot stress this enough, add the `.exe` extension too when running under Windows, correct  is`powershell.exe`. If you happen to use just `powershell` and `nodepad` will all of a sudden pop-up echoing your script, you will have a hard time trying to figure it out.

**index.js**

```
const powerShell = require('./powerShell');

let seconds = 5;
let remaining = seconds;
let nd = new Date().getTime() + (seconds * 1000);

setInterval(() => {
    remaining -= 1
    let time = new Date();
    console.log('Your code running at:', time.toTimeString());

    if (remaining === 3) {
        console.log('Opening powershell...')
        powerShell([
            "-File",
            "./showTime.ps1"
        ]);
    }

    if (time.getTime() > nd) {
        console.log('Main script will exit.');
        process.exit(0);
    }
}, 1000);
```

**powerShell.js**

```
module.exports = (spawnArguments) => {
    if (typeof spawnArguments === "undefined" || !(spawnArguments instanceof Array)) {
        spawnArguments = [];
    }
    const {spawn} = require('child_process');
    let defaultPowerShellArguments = ["-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass", "-NoExit",];
    let powershell = spawn('powershell.exe', [...defaultPowerShellArguments, ...spawnArguments], {
        shell: true,
        detached: true,
        // You can tell PowerShell to open straight to the file directory
        // Then you can use the relative path of your file.
        // cwd: 'ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_A_VALID_FOLDER'
        // cwd: 'C:/'
    });
}
```

**showTime.ps1**

```
Get-Date -Format G
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you'll need to pass the `shell` option to tell `node` which shell to execute the command on. This defaults to `process.env.ComSpec` on Windows, which if for whatever reason isn't set will then default to `cmd.exe`.

Reference: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_default_windows_shell:

> Although Microsoft specifies %COMSPEC% must contain the path to 'cmd.exe' in the root environment, child processes are not always subject to the same requirement. Thus, in child_process functions where a shell can be spawned, 'cmd.exe' is used as a fallback if process.env.ComSpec is unavailable.

PowerShell shell support has been made available via [this commit](https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/af883e1f99598492474c13447e2a1895c0c6f1b7).

Since the `exec` command is working, I'd suggest starting there and trying to get the window to show. Try passing `shell: 'PowerShell'` in the options object. `windowsHide` defaults to `false` for `child_process.exec`, but it might not hurt to pass it as well:

```
exec('powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ' + updater_path, { shell: 'PowerShell', windowsHide: false }, function callback(error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log(error);
});
```

You may also be able to get it working with `spawn` with similar options: `{ shell: 'PowerShell', windowsHide: false }`

Comment: I will try this to see if it works, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Okay, so this does essentially the same thing as my "current code" section in my question.